# Does the spread operator not copy over the prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

The following code does not appear to copy over an object's prototype.

```
const animalProto = {
 eat() {
  // function body
 },

 sleep() {
  // function body
 },
}

function animalCreator(proto, attributes) {
 return {...Object.create(proto), ...attributes}
}

const cat = animalCreator(animalProto, { name: 'garfield' })

cat.eat() // this is an error; function is not defined; it doesn't appear to link the prototype chain.
```

If I replace the spread with the following it works:

```
return Object.assign(Object.create(proto), attributes)
```

Essentially my question is why does `Object.assign` work but not the spread operator. Is there something `Object.assign` is doing that the spread operator is missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

> It copies **own enumerable** properties from a provided object onto a new object.

"Own enumerable" means that properties on the prototype will not be included.

If you spread an object with inherited properties (such as an object immediately created with `Object.create`), none of those inherited properties will be present in the result.

`Object.assign` is slightly different - it assigns all properties to the right of the first *to the first*. It would be more similar to spread if you had passed an empty object as the first argument:

```
return Object.assign({}, Object.create(proto), attributes)
```

in which case nothing in `proto` would be reflected in the output.

```js
const proto = { foo: 'bar' };
const result = Object.assign({}, Object.create(proto), { another: 'prop' });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I definitely overlooked that part in the docs, perfect explanation.

Comment: Isn't Object.assign() the same as spread operator on only copying the enumerable and own properties (from source object to target object)?

Comment: @Galaxy Pretty much - the only real difference is that with spread syntax, the "target" object is always empty (and so can't have any prototypal-inherited properties, other than those on `Object.prototype`), whereas with `Object.assign`, the first argument (the same object that the `Object.assign` call resolves to) may be an object which *does* have prototypal-inherited properties

Answer (score 5):

`Object.create()` makes a new object that is prototype linked to the object passed to it. This means that the returned object doesn't get a copy of the parent's attributes, it just has a link to the parent prototype. The object spread only copies the objects own enumerable properties, which doesn't include those up the prototype chain.

```js
const animalProto = {
 eat() {
  // function body
 },

 sleep() {
  // function body
 },
}

let o = Object.create(animalProto)
// o doesn't have it's own eat or sleep.
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o))

console.log({...o}) // empty
```