# React use class object as prop with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The example below outputs an instance of SomeClass - this works as expected. Question: Is there a way to omit the DisplayModelComponentProps interface and directly pass the object to be displayed as prop?

```
class SomeClass {
  public someProperty:string = "some string";
  public someFunction():string { return "another string"; }
}

interface DisplayModelComponentProps {
    obj:SomeClass
}

const DisplayModelComponent: React.FC<DisplayModelComponentProps> = props => {
  return(<p>{props.obj.someProperty}</p>
  )
}

export function Test(): JSX.Element {
 const someObj:SomeClass = new SomeClass();
 const props = { obj: someObj }

  return(<div><DisplayModelComponent {...props}></DisplayModelComponent></div>)
}
```

When I change the code so the DisplayModelComponent takes a SomeClass as prop I get this error (because the function is lost on destructuring):

```
Property 'someFunction' is missing in type '{ someProperty: string; }' but required in type 'SomeClass'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because when spreading the instance of `SomeClass` the `someFunction` property is lost. That's why Typescript is complaining that `someFunction` is missing in the component props.

You can check this answer regarding the spread operator and how properties are copied: [Does the spread operator not copy over the prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164518/does-the-spread-operator-not-copy-over-the-prototype)

With that in mind, I don't think you are going to be able to do it as long as methods are involved in the class you are trying to use as interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured out this would do the job but its definetely not a clean solution: `return(<div><DisplayModelComponent {...{...someObj, someFunction:()=>""}}></DisplayModelComponent></div>)`